# Why laravel password not match?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to login but always fail.

this how i store my password

```
'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
```

In laravel LoginController .

```
public function customchecker()
    {
        $credentials = [
          'username'        => Input::get('username'),
          'password'        => bcrypt(Input::get('password'))
        ];

         if (Auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
              return Redirect::to('home')->with('alert-success', 'You are now logged in.'); 

          }else{

            $errors = ['username' => ['Email and/or password invalid.']]; 

            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput(Input::except('password')); 
          }

    }
```

i test with this

```
$credentials = [
          'username'        => Input::get('username'),
          'password'        => Input::get('password')
        ];
```

still not working, How can i fix this ?

Comment: The ```check``` method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash. However, if you are using the ```LoginController``` included with Laravel, you will probably not need to use this directly, as this controller automatically calls this method. From Laravel Docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/hashing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In credentials you shouldn't bcrypt password, you should just pass plain text password, so instead of:

```
    $credentials = [
      'username'        => Input::get('username'),
      'password'        => bcrypt(Input::get('password'))
    ];
```

use:

```
    $credentials = [
      'username'        => Input::get('username'),
      'password'        => Input::get('password')
    ];
```

and it will work.

Under the hood something like this is done later:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

so as you see plain password is used later to compare if password is valid.

Comment: where do i put `validateCredentials()` ?

Comment: sorry, i'm new with laravel